# Copy data from a workbook to another workbook adding a new row each time for the input data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a relative newbie to macros, what I have learnt is now forgotten, and I need some advice on the best way to write a macro.

The task is to open a file and copy some data from this file  to a separate workbook , adding a new row for each file opened.

I am trying to use ActiveRow to advance the row but get a 1004 error

Any assistance would be appreciated, even just basic code to copy data to a row and then move down one row, I can hopefully build the rest up from there.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to show some code and the specific problem, or we can not guess as to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
TwoAfterLastRow = Workbooks("YourWorkbookName").Sheets("YourSheetName").Cells(rows.count, "RifColumnLetter").End(xlup).row +2
```

so, for example:

```
TwoAfterLastRow = Workbooks("Cartel1").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2
```